# Match before but dont include in result

Tags: php, regex

My Regex:

```
(?<=(?i)start\s+date\s+)([0-9]{2}[\.]{1}[0-9]{2}[\.]{1}[0-9]{4})
```

I am trying to match a date which is preceded by the words 'start date' but only want the date to be returned.

So for example a match of 'start date     01.01.2000' should return '01.01.2000', I know I am close but I cant seem to get the first part of my expression to not be included in the results. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=start\sdate)\s+([0-9]{2}[\.]{1}[0-9]{2}[\.]{1}[0-9]{4})
```

will work. I think the problem is with \s+, variable length look behind. Most regex engines don't implement variable length look behinds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=start\sdate\s)([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are always looking for a string that matches `start date ##.##.####`, this would do:

```
start date ([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})
```

however in that case, you could also simply do

```
substr($string, strrpos($string, "start date ") + 11, 10);
```